# How to Store Json data into Sql table in asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, mysql

I want to store Json data into a table using Jquery  & Ajax.This is my Json file looks like:-

```
[
{
"term": "BACCHUS",
"part": "n.",
"definition": "A convenient deity invented by the ancients as an excuse for getting drunk.",
"quote": [
"Is public worship, then, a sin,",
"That for devotions paid to Bacchus",
"The lictors dare to run us in,",
"And resolutely thump and whack us?"
],
"author": "Jorace"
},
{
"term": "BACKBITE",
"part": "v.t.",
"definition": "To speak of a man as you find him when he can't find you."
},
{
"term": "BEARD",
"part": "n.",
"definition": "The hair that is commonly cut off by those who justly execrate the absurd Chinese custom of shaving the head."
}
]
```

I have table named "json" with three columns having names term,part and definition. Right now i have just loading json data into html table like this.

```
   $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "b.json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (entryIndex, entry) {
                //   var html = '<div class="declareing_variable">';
                var html1 = entry['term'];
                var html2 = '<div class="geting_part">' + entry['part'] + '</div>';
                var html3 = '<div class="geting_definition">' + entry['definition'] + '</div>';
                $('<tr></tr>').html('<th>' + html1 + '</th><th>$' + html2 + '</td><th>$' + html3 + '</th>').appendTo('#json');
                $('#abc').append(html2);

            });
        }
    });
```

Can anyone please tell me how can i store it into sql table and can provide some coding help?

Comment: jQuery does not talk to databases. And b.json is unlikely to be a real url. You need a language like PHP to do that.

Comment: actually need it in asp.net C# project .I hope we can do it in C#.
Btw b.json file is placed in current directly.

Comment: You need to send one more ajax request with the required data as jQuery cannot talk directly to the server. Then you need to store this data to the DB using a sql query or stored proc..

Answer (score 0):

What's your server-side programming language?

if that's PHP you can use JSON_DECODE() to decode json data that you've sent to web server:  [json_decode() on PHP website](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

However, since you're using C#, you'd need to use something like [this JSON Library on Codeplex](http://json.codeplex.com) to decode your JSON.